# gettest trannslation or install doesn't find language

Tags: python, internationalization

I try to implement i18n with Python in a solution of mine, to do so I've created a tryOut.py

I have the following folder structure:

- \bin\languages
- \bin\languages\de
- \bin\languages\de\LC_MESSAGES  #po&mo files are located here
- \tryOut.py

I try now to create a translation from default (english) to german with this program:

```
import gettext
import os

localdir = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'bin\languages')
gettext.install('tryOut',localdir)
print(localdir)
setLang = "de"


def greet():
    'Prints out greeting message.'
    age = 25
    print(_('Hi'))
    print(_("What's up?"))
    print(_('I am {age} years old!').format(age=20))
    print('\n')

def select_language(language,localdir):
    lang = gettext.translation('tryOut',localdir,languages=[language],fallback=True)
    gettext.install('tryOut',localdir)

greet()

select_language('de',localdir)
greet()

select_language('en',localdir)
greet()
```

But the translation doesn't appear.

I tried to use the documentation of gettext to solve this, but I don't see my issue at the moment. Could you please help me with this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution/error the issues was the section:

```
def select_language(language,localdir):
lang = gettext.translation('tryOut',localdir,languages=[language],fallback=True)
gettext.install('tryOut',localdir)
```

I need to load the lang.install instead of gettext.install:

```
def select_language(language,localdir):
lang = gettext.translation('tryOut',localdir,languages=[language],fallback=True)
lang.install('tryOut')
```